# How to print last_name as well in .txt file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I have this file on a Linux machine:

```
<names>
<first_name>Mohammed Sani</first_name>
<last_name>ABACHA</last_name>
<aliases>
<alias>ABACHE,Mohammed Sani</alias>
<alias>SANI,Mohammed</alias>
</aliases>
<low_quality_aliases>
<alias xsi:nil="true"/>
</low_quality_aliases>
<alternative_spelling xsi:nil="true"/>
</names>
```

I am using the command below to print the names, but it only prints the first name:

```
sed -n 's:.*<first_name>\(.*\)</first_name>.*:\1:p' 'test.xml' > name.txt
```

How can I append the last name as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract an attribute value from XML](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529670/extract-an-attribute-value-from-xml)

Comment: tl;dr: don't use `sed`, use a proper XML parser

Comment: Do you just want to _output_ the first and last names, or do you want to do something else with them?

Comment: only first and last name

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the first and last name data on the same line, with a tab character in-between them:

Using `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/names' \
    -v 'first_name' -nl \
    -v 'last_name' -nl file.xml 2>/dev/null |
paste - -
```

The `xmlstarlet` command parses out the values of the `first_name` and `last_name` nodes under the `names` node, and outputs these on one line each.

The two lines of output is pasted onto a single line with a tab character as delimiter using `paste`.  Use e.g. `-d ','` with `paste` to get comma-delimited output.

I'm redirecting the standard error stream to `/dev/null` because there are some bogus namespace declarations later on in the document that `xmlstarlet` rightly complains about.

---

Using `xq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/:

```bsh
xq -r '.names | [ .first_name, .last_name ] | @tsv' file.xml
```

This uses the `@tsv` operator to create tab-delimited output. It outputs the same data as the `xmlstarlet` code above, but instead of an XPath expression, we're using a `jq` expression.

Change `@tsv` to `@csv` to get fully quoted CSV output instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can either add a second `s` command:

```
sed -n 's:.*<first_name>\(.*\)</first_name>.*:\1:p;s:.*<last_name>\(.*\)</last_name>.*:\1:p' 'test.xml' > name.txt
```

or use an extended regular expression:

```
sed -En 's:.*<(first|last)_name>(.*)</\1_name>.*:\2:p' 'test.xml' > name.txt
```

**Update: Request to output both names in the same line**

To have the output on the same line, you can simply pipe it through another script to join lines with a whitespace:

```
sed -En 's:.*<(first|last)_name>(.*)</\1_name>.*:\2:p' test.xml | sed 'H;1h;$!d;g;s/\n/ /g' > name.txt
```

The `H,1h;$1d;g` is used to join all lines in the pattern space (`H` appends all lines to the hold space, `1h` overwrites the hold space for the first line to avoid a preceding newline, `$!d` stops processing for all but the the last line and `g` move the hold space contents to the pattern space), then `s/\n/ /g` replaces all newlines with white spaces; in your case you could drop the `g` if you are sure there will be always only two lines.

On linux, you probably have GNU `sed` and could do `sed -z 's/\n/ /g'` for the same result.

More elegantly, and capable of dealing with multiple name pairs in one file, you could also do something like

```
sed -e '/.*<first_name>\(.*\)<\/first_name>.*/{s//\1/;h;}' -e '/.*<last_name>\(.*\)<\/last_name>.*/!d;s//\1/;H;g;s/\n/ /' 'test.xml' > name.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, @Philippos, but it's printing the last name in the next line.Can we have in same line?

Comment: @ShashiShanker please edit your question and add your expected output so we don't need to guess what you need.

Comment: @ShashiShanker I did update the answer to have the names in the same line.